# Creating a minimal desktop environment to run EmulationStation

Tags: desktop-environments, emulation

I found “[Start ubuntu without a desktop environment but start an X application](/q/310671)” and wanted to try it out for myself, but this time launching [EmulationStation](http://www.emulationstation.org/) and created a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/xsessions/` with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=EmulationStation
Name=EmulationStation
Comment=Launch Retropie with the EmulationStation frontend.
```

Running the desktop environment shows a error:

```
Xsession:unable to launch "EmulationStation" 
X session ---"EmulationStation" not found; falling back to default session.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I am trying to get a text only environment for just emulationstation to launch just off SSDM and trying to avoid using a different user for running LXQt.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the executable `EmulationStation` is not in the list of directories that are searched for executables when no directory is specified (i. e. the content of the environment variable `PATH`). You can use the full, absolute path to the executable in the `Exec=` entry instead.